# Aligning printed strings in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text, text-alignment

```
print('The most frequent bigram tags are:\n')
bigram = bigram_frequency(lines)
for i in bigram:
    print(i[0]+"\t\t"+str(i[1]))
```

here's what I get:

```
N+N         5
N+DELM      3
DELM+DELM         2
N+P         2
DELM+P      2
P+N         2
DELM+N      2
CON+N       2
N+CON       2
```

How should I align that funny `2` from the third row with the rest of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youc can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format):

```
for i in [('fgd',1),('dg',2),('ggdd',3),( 'dd',4)]:
    print("{:5s} {:5d}".format(i[0], i[1]))


fgd       1
dg        2
ggdd      3
dd        4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting to get a specific text width, padded with spaces:

```
for tag, frequency in bigram:
    print('{tag:10} {frequency}'.format(tag=tag, frequency=frequency))
```

Change the `10` to the maximum width of the first column.